# Qt Unit test a function using QDBusargument

Tags: qt, dbus, unit-testing

I have a small, and what should be simple, but it not :)
I have this small function that takes a QVariant, the QVariant will contain a QDBusArgument.
The problem is that creating a Unit test for this function seams to be a bit hard.

Creating the QDBusArgument then fill it with data, and pass it to the function.

```
Metadata MetaData::getMetadata(QVariant value){
    Metadata _metadata;
    _metadata.clear();

    const QDBusArgument &optionsArgument = qvariant_cast<QDBusArgument>(value);
    QString error;

    //To ensure that we have correct data type as we expect key value
    if(optionsArgument.currentType()==QDBusArgument::MapType)
    {
        _metadata = MetaData::decodeMapType(value, error);
    }else{
        _metadata.insert("error","not map type");
    }

    return _metadata;
}
```

I tried to do the following
    static QDBusArgument mArg;

```
mArg.beginMap(QVariant::Int,QVariant::String);
int _key = 1;
QString _value = "test2";
mArg.beginMapEntry();
mArg << _key << _value;
mArg.endMapEntry();
mArg.endMap();

qDebug()<<mArg.currentSignature();
```

When doing the qDebug I get a trying to read from a write only property

And this seams to be the main problem, It is possible to create the QDBusArgument fill it with data, but it will not possible to read it, So it is not intended to be used like that, leading to the fact, that unit test of function that takes QDBusArgument as imput is quite diffecult.

Br.
Michael

Comment: anyone? trying to do a unit test myself, and I can't...  
I even tried with QDBusMetaType::demarshall and QDBusMetaType::marshall